# Use Git branches for book chapters

Tags: git, branch

I want to provide the sample code for a book in a GitHub repository.

The reader should be able to checkout the successive stages of the code corresponding to each of the chapters.

First I thought about tagging but then, even after the book is finished, I might want to fix the sample code of any chapter.  Thus, my guess is that branching is the way to go.

For each chapter I would create a new branch using the previous chapter as the basis:  `git branch <chapter2> <chapter1>`.

I would then be able to checkout any branch, that is, any chapter and fix it.

I would never merge the various branches as there is no *final product* to speak of.

If I fix something in, say, chapter 3, I would checkout that branch fix it and commit.  Previous chapters would be left alone, but what would happen to chapters 4 through last? My guess is that unless I merge them, any changes made to chapter 3 would not affect the following chapters. Those chapters/branches would slowly veer apart.  Am I right?

Should I actually want to apply a change to all chapters, I would have to do it on each separately.  Is it so?

Alternatively, I could develop the sample code on master and then, for each chapter, I would create a branch named after the chapter just finished.  I would then carry on working on master for the next chapter.  I assume the branch would remain pointing to the the state of master at the point I made the branch and not get the changes I make in master.  Is that so?  At that point, the branch would be nothing more than a sort of tag, as it would have not actually branched out of what master was at that point.

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with creating a directory for each chapter, all on master?

Answer (score 2):

Background: Branches and tags are different ways of [referring to commits on disk](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/experimenting-with-git/references-make-commits-reachable.html).

The simplest way is probably just to put all the code for all the chapters in one repository, possibly in subdirectories.  You can tag releases and update whatever you want, whenever you want.

If you really want a separate checkout for each chapter, and there is no merged final product, I would put each chapter in its own repo.  That way you have independent history and it's clear to readers that the chapters are independent.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use branches.

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/nirgeier/ExpressJSPhotoApp/branches) which I'm using to to teach express (node.js).
Each step is in its own branch and user can compare steps to view the changes between each step.

> Should I actually want to apply a change to all chapters, I would have to do it on each separately. Is it so?

You can use cherry pick to add your commits to all the desired branches. Use the [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) command to automatically fix conflicts.